# Create "dead space" beneath GBoard to move it up

Tags: gboard

I have bought a Samsung Galaxy A50. The problem is, that with the navigation menu completly disabled, as well as the almost completly gone bessel, the keyboard is way too far down for me to comfortably type.

I know that there is the float option for GBoard, but that doesn't really work for me, as the app gets full screen in the background, which makes it hard to see what you type or generally blocks information.

Is there some way to add dead space beneath the Gboard?